# Cannot compare passed value with column name. Laravel

Tags: compare, laravel-5, where-clause

I'm trying to use where clause for comparing the values that has been passed from route which is id. For this, I have used following code:

```
Route::get('Bill/{id}/students',['uses' =>'BillController@student']);
```

I need to compare id with the column name in controller which is grade_id. For this Following code has been used:

```
public function student($id)
{
    $data['id'] = $id;      
    $students=Student::all()->where('grade_id',$data);

    return view('bill.students',compact('students'));
}
```

But it is returning empty values.
If I pass direct value 1 instead of $data. It works perfectly fine. 
Can anyone provide me solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `whereLoose()` instead of `where()`

> **whereLoose()** This method has the same signature as the where method;
>   however, all values are compared using "loose" comparisons

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-whereloose)

**Why this happening?**

`$data` have a `String` type and you are comparing String with `Int` type even if you pass numeric value `$data` will be String type.

```
(1 === '1') //False 
(1 === 1) //True
(1 == '1') //True
```